# IDE recommendation for PHP

Tags: php, ide

I am new to PHP development, any recommended IDE for PHP? Better for both convenience of reading code and debug code.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Use netbeans or zend editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try "*The world’s most powerful open-source web development IDE*" - http://www.aptana.com/,
It has also a PHP debugger and a lot of plugins derived from the Eclipse world.

Answer (score 0):

**Aptana Studio 3** - easily my number 1 choice. Excellent Intellisense support for PHP. Very colour customizable. Also, a great support community. I use it for literally all the languages I program in.

Have a look here: http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download